# What is wrong with my program for Text I/O - Java

Tags: java, text, io

I've been trying to make a program that reads a text file of ASCII decimal values, translates it to strings and prints them out on a different text file.

Here's what I have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class ReadData {
 Scanner inFile;
 PrintWriter outFile;
  int number;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadData rd = new ReadData();
    rd.Run2();
    rd.Run3();
   }

 public void Run2() {
  String fileName = "ASCII.txt"; // text file that has the decimal values
  try {
   inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   System.err.printf("ERROR: Cannot open %s\n", fileName);
   System.exit(1);
  }
  while (inFile.hasNext()) {
   number = inFile.nextInt();
   System.out.print(number + "   ");
  }

 }

 public void Run3() {
   try {
    outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt")); // the name of text file that should have the translated ASCII values
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
  }
number = inFile.nextInt(); // the decimal values in ASCII.txt
 char ch = (char)(number); // translating the values to corresponding char values
      outFile.print(ch);
     inFile.close();
  outFile.close();
 }

}
```

It compiles successfully and prints out the decimal values fine but I get an error after the decimal values are printed and the output.txt file is blank... What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If you have decimal values, why are you using `nextInt()`?

Comment: Post your entire error/exception and stack trace into you question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reinitialize the Scanner. You ran the Scanner to the end of the file in Run2(). In Run3() the Scanner is at the end of the file already and throws an Exception. All you have to do is remove the while loop in Run2() and you'll be fine.

ps: Java standards suggest methods are not capitalized.

Comment: I did what you said and just put the while loop in Run3(), and it worked! Thanks!